# Recommendation on Query Efficiency : 2 different versions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

which of these is more efficient query to run:

one where the INCLUDE / DON'T INCLUDE filter condition in WHERE clause and tested for each row

```
SELECT distinct fullvisitorid
FROM `google.com:analytics-bigquery.LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910` t, unnest(hits) as ht
WHERE (select max(if(cd.index = 1,cd.value,null))from unnest(ht.customDimensions) cd) 
       = 'high_worth'
```

one returning all rows and then outer SELECT clause doing all filtering test to INCLUDE / DON'T INCLUDE

```
SELECT distinct fullvisitorid
FROM 
    (
     SELECT 
        fullvisitorid
        , (select max(if(cd.index = 1,cd.value,null)) FROM unnest(ht.customDimensions) cd) hit_cd_1
     FROM `google.com:analytics-bigquery.LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910` t
          , unnest(hits) as ht
     )
WHERE
   hit_cd_1 = 'high_worth'
```

Both produce exactly same results!
the goal is: list of fullvisitorId, who ever sent hit Level Custom Dimension (index =1) with value = 'high_worth' users ()

Thanks for your inputs!

Cheers!

/Vibhor

Comment: Did you try it? What were the results? You should also check the query explanations: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-plan-explanation

Comment: obviously - they are identical even though you slightly rearranged appearance. so from those two you should choose whatever easier for you to read/maintain. I would pick first query - but it is really matter of personal preferences

Answer (score 1):

I tried the two queries and compared their [explanations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-plan-explanation), they are identical. I am assuming some sort of optimization magic occurs prior to the query being ran.

Comment: Thanks Ying.. yeah, even when I run on large dataset.. there's no clear winner... So, I'm a bit lost, if one is more preferable over other as per best practices or is it just a matter if choice. If more experience people in query optimisation area have any feedback...

Comment: It's not that they are similar in efficiency... It's that they are identical. So I think it's internally optimized by BigQuery. It probably used some functional equivalency or something under the hood.

But purely from a logical point of view, it would see like SELECT level filtering would be more efficient. That way, you theoretically speaking only return entries that fit the bill. WHERE clause seems to suggest you are filtering after the fact.

That being said, BQ seems to do optimization magic that make the two identical.

Comment: you mean the 1st query (only single SELECT clause) will be more efficient theoretically.. over the 2nd one (2 level SELECT filter)

Comment: Yes indeed, the 1st "should" be more efficient. I would suggest using that just for best practice purposes.

Answer (score 0):

As of your original two queries: obviously - they are identical even though you slightly rearranged appearance. so from those two you should choose whatever easier for you to read/maintain. I would pick first query - but it is really matter of personal preferences

Meantime, try below (BigQuery Standard SQL) - it looks slightly optimized to me - but I didn't have chance to test on real data

```
SELECT DISTINCT fullvisitorid
FROM `google.com:analytics-bigquery.LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910` t, 
UNNEST(hits) AS ht, UNNEST(ht.customDimensions) cd
WHERE cd.index = 1 AND cd.value = 'high_worth'
```

Obviously - it should produce same result as your two queries
Execution plan looks better to me and it (query) is faster is much easier to read / manage